# Increment value each time when you run function

Tags: javascript

So I need a function which increments the value of a variable say n=0. When ever the function runs, the value of this varible must be incremented and it should not be equal to 0 again. For example consider the following code :

```
function increment(){
  var n = 0;
  n++;
  return n;
}
```

Now everytime you run this function you get a value of 1. But my requirement is if you run this function for the 1st time, it should be 1, if you run it for the second time, it should be 2 and so on. Unless you refresh the html page and run the function again, it should not be equal to 0. Can anybody help me?

I'm new to coding and any small help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to declare n outside of the function.

```
var n = 0;

function increment(){

  n++;
  return n;
}
```

The problem is scopes.  when you declare a variable inside of a function it is bound to the local scope of the function.  as soon as the function is done the variable is gone.

declaring the variable in the root level of the script places it in the global scope.

another way to do this would be to have a variable outside that you're passing around and then you pass it to the function via a parameter.

```
var i = 0;

function increment(n){

  n++;
  return n;
}

i=increment(i);
```

for more information on scopes and variables, review this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope

Comment: +1, but can be simplified to `function increment() { return ++n; }`

Comment: I'm not going for simple, I'm going or informative :)

Answer (score 47):

Create a [`closure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) to hold the value

> Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables.
>
> In short, variables from the parent function of the closure remain bound from the parent's scope.

```js
var increment = (function(n) {
  return function() {
    n += 1;
    return n;
  }
}(0)); // -1 if you want the first increment to return 0

console.log(increment());
console.log(increment());
console.log(increment());
```

Comment: Ok thanks for answering the above qn. My main motive for this is that I wanted to implement a system in which a button must change it's color when clicked and it should change back to it's original color when clicked again. Any suggestions??

Comment: @Gopal1216 the easiest way would be to use jQuery. add a toggle class to the click that will add a css class to it.  But it's a bit off topic for this question, why don't you open a new question directly asking what you're looking for?

Comment: Just as easy to use plain Javascript. :) But definitely off topic for this question. Create another question.

Comment: var increment = (function(n) {
  return function() {
       return ++n;
  }
}(0));

Comment: How to make it work across several modules?

Answer (score 11):

You can bind the data to the function (since functions are objects).

```
function increment(){
    increment.n = increment.n || 0;
    return ++increment.n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about making the number of times increment was called a parameter ?

```
function increment(numberOfIncrementCalls){
numberOfIncrementCalls++;
return numberOfIncrementCalls;
}
```

```js
function increment(numberOfIncrementCalls){
    numberOfIncrementCalls++;
    return numberOfIncrementCalls;
    }
n = document.getElementById("demo");
o = document.getElementById("event");
numOfIncr = 0;
o.addEventListener("click",function(){
numOfIncr = increment(numOfIncr);
var insert = numOfIncr.toString();
n.innerHTML = insert;
});
```

```html
<html>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button id="event">Click me</button>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = 0;
function increment(){
  n++;
  return n;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for answering the above qn. My main motive for this is that I wanted to implement a system in which a button must change it's color when clicked and it should change back to it's original colo when clicked again. Any suggestions??

Comment: Look at jquery toggleClass()

Answer (score 0):

Learning about scopes will help you greatly. What you want here is the variable 'n' to be of a global scope.

```
 var n = 0; //Declare n outside of the function makes it accessible to the function
            //and to any other functions or expressions that want access to n
 function inc() {
     n++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

***You can try this code and store the value in localstorage. All time it will be increase old Value untill you have not clear localstorage...***

```
<script>
    localStorage.setItem("n", 0);
    increment();
    function increment(){
    let n;
    n = localStorage.getItem('n');
    n++;
    localStorage.setItem("n", n);
    return n;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call a function the value will be incremented by +1 by this method --

```
let x = 0;
function increment (){
return x = x + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will always return 501

```
a=500;
function increment(n){
return n+1
}
increment(a);
```

You could equate a to the function
a=increment(a);
That would set a to 501, then 502 etc

However consider using an array for the argument instead

```
a=[500];
function increment(n){
n[0]++;
}
increment(a);
```

Now it will increment the value of a[0] even though it doesn't have a return statement. The benefit of this is it means we can have multiple arguments and increment them all, and then return some other variable if you like. Like this

```
a=[0];
b=[5];

function incrementToTen(n,o)
{
n[0]++;
o[0]++;
if(n[0]>=10||o[0]>=10)
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
```

So after running incrementToTen(a,b) 5 times it will return true