# how do I trace a fibonacci recursive function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, fibonacci

I was writing a recursive function for fibonacci sequence and wanted to use a counter to keep track of the recursive calls i.e. how many calls it takes to finish this function

in this case it is 15.

[image]

```
fibonacci(num) {
  if(num<2) {
    return num;
  }
  return fibonacci(num-1)+fibonacci(num-2);}
```

I understand this function is really well-known and it's not the best approach to solve fibonacci sequence from a runtime standpoint.

I still have a hard time printing out the number of steps it took

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21839980/2970947 or even https://stackoverflow.com/a/21840024/2970947

Answer (score 1):

```
let counter = 0;    
function fibonacci(num) {
  counter++;
  if(num < 2) { return num; }
  return fibonacci(num-1)+fibonacci(num-2);
}
console.log(counter);
```

Comment: The general approach is correct, but did you mean to wrap this in an IIFE, or somehow otherwise call it correctly?

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let counter = 0;    
function fibonacci(num) {
  counter++;
  if(num < 2) { return num; }
  return fibonacci(num-1)+fibonacci(num-2);
}
fibonacci(5);// if number is 5

console.log('Number of Times '+ counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

One surprising way this is made easy is by use of continuation passing style

We add a continuation parameter `k` and assign it a default value of `console.log`. In the base case, when `n` is less than 2, we call the continuation with `n` and a count of `1`. In the inductive case, `n` is 2 or greater, so we call `fib` for `n - 1` and `n - 2`, capture the return values of each in a continuation, and lastly call the input continuation with the combined result, adding a `+ 1` for the current `n`

You'll also notice it does not require global variables

```js
const fib = (n = 0, k = console.log) =>
  n < 2
    ? k (n, 1)
    : fib (n - 1, (a, aCount) =>
        fib (n - 2, (b, bCount) =>
          k (a + b, aCount + bCount + 1)))
          
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1)
  fib (i)
  
// 0 1
// 1 1
// 1 3
// 2 5
// 3 9
// 5 15 <this is your test case>
// 8 25
// 13 41
// 21 67
// 34 109
```

The default continuation just logs to the console, but we can provide our own continuation to do something more interesting with the result - this is also one technique used to simulate the return of multiple values

```
for (let n = 0; n < 10; n = n + 1)
  fib (n, (res, count) =>
    console.log ("after %d computations, fib (%d) returned %d", count, n, res))

// after 1 computations, fib (0) returned 0
// after 1 computations, fib (1) returned 1
// after 3 computations, fib (2) returned 1
// after 5 computations, fib (3) returned 2
// after 9 computations, fib (4) returned 3
// after 15 computations, fib (5) returned 5
// after 25 computations, fib (6) returned 8
// after 41 computations, fib (7) returned 13
// after 67 computations, fib (8) returned 21
```

Here's the same function using the older `function` syntax

```
const fib = function (n = 0, k = console.log) {
  if (n < 2)
    return k (n, 1)
  else
    return fib (n - 1, function (a, aCount) {
      return fib (n - 2, function (b, bCount) {
        return k (a + b, 1 + aCount + bCount)
      })
    })
}
```