# Increments changing every function run as variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables, closures

I have found the simple solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839918/increment-value-each-time-when-you-run-function) using `closure` from [@Xotic750](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592253/xotic750)

**But, Is it possible to run function without round brackets?** *E.G.*:

```
var increment = new Increment()

console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: 1
console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: 2
console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: 3
```

Every function run I have got the *function* as `[object Object]` in `console.log` instead of `value` :

```
    var Increment = (function(n) {
      return function() {
        n += 1;
        return n;
      }
    }(0)); 

    var increment = new Increment();

    console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: [object Object]
    console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: [object Object]
    console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: [object Object]
```

Comment: To call an ordinary function you need a parenthesized argument list. There can be no arguments but you need the `()`.

Comment: @Pointy that won't help here.  This example is a lot more complicated than it needs to be. Increment is a function, but you are calling it with  `new` which returns an object.

Comment: @MarkMeyer well even when `Increment()` is called as a constructor the explicitly returned object will still be the result value. If the OP took `new` away it still wouldn't work, but the problem has nothing to do with that. When a constructor explicitly returns an object (whether it's the constructed object or not), that overrides the effect of `new`.

Comment: I understand that @Pointy -- but the way it's used here, the return value will be the result of calling `new` on the inner function because that's what returned by the IEFE.

Comment: @MarkMeyer oh oh, I see what you mean. Yea that's a mess; however for the actual question asked, the answer is still "no" short of a getter (can't do that with a plain variable) or something like the `.toString()` hack mentioned in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are printing the `increment` instances, there is a `toString` conversion happening. You could use that to perform the increment:

```js
var Increment = (function(n) {
  var f = function() {}; // Only serves as constructor
  f.prototype.toString = function() {
    n += 1;
    return n;
  }
  return f
}(0)); 

var increment = new Increment();

console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: 1
console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: 2
console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: 3
```

Be aware, the counter is kinda global. If you want the counter to be separate and restart from 0 for each instance, then use `this`:

```js
var Increment = (function(n) {
  var f = function() {
      this.n = 0;
  };
  f.prototype.toString = function() {
    this.n += 1;
    return this.n;
  }
  return f
}(0)); 

var increment = new Increment();

console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: 1
console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: 2
console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: 3

increment = new Increment();

console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: 1
console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: 2
console.log('value: ' + increment) // value: 3
```

Comment: that's a good idea, though I would have a serious talk with a developer who did that in my codebase :)

Comment: Sure, I am open to even have that talk with the OP :)

Comment: @trincot  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an object of the function `Increment` by using the `new` keyword. In your case, you would simply want to call the `Increment` function as so:

```
console.log('value: ' + Increment());
console.log('value: ' + Increment());
console.log('value: ' + Increment());
```

See this link on [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Closure) for a more detailed explanation as to how they work.

Comment: I think the OP wants the `increment` variable to act like a getter and run code each time its value is interrogated.

Comment: @Ben Beck, Thank you. Yes I know that it works, but I need to get it from **new variable, without using round brackets**;

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to run function without round brackets

Yes, you can do that using a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), here is an example:

```js
class Cls {
   constructor() {
      this.value = 0;
   }
   get increment() {
      return this.value++
   }
}

const cls = new Cls()

console.log('value: ' + cls.increment)
console.log('value: ' + cls.increment)
console.log('value: ' + cls.increment)
```