# how do i create a simple onclick add function()

Tags: javascript

i try to do these code and expecting it for increase by 1 everytime i click on the button but it returns me NaN instead.
im really new to javascript. really hope someone could help me!
thanks in advance.

```
function add(){
  var sum = parseInt(1);
  var adding = adding + sum;
  document.getElementById("amt1").innerText = adding;
}
```

Comment: you must first initial  'adding' variable then use it, 
test this : var adding = 0;  adding = adding+sum;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a closure over the `sum` and take the returned function for adding to the value.

```js
var add = function(sum) {
    return function () {
        document.getElementById("amt1").innerHTML = ++sum;
    };
}(0);
```

```html
<span id="amt1">0</span> <button onclick="add()">add</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see, here you've asked two problems:

1. **Why `adding` is `NaN`**

   At line #2, you haven't initialized variable `adding`, hence in RHS `adding` is `undefined`.

   Therefore, the RHS block `adding + sum;` is evaluated as `undefined + 1`, which evaluates to `NaN`
2. **How to use `onClick()`**

   > [W3School's tutorial on onClick()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

---

**Here is your code in working state (HTML + JavaScript):**

```js
var adding = 0; // initialization. This is the step, that your code was missing

function add() {
 var sum = parseInt(1);
  adding = adding + sum;
  document.getElementById("amt1").innerText = adding;
}
```

```html
<h1>The onclick Event</h1>
<button onclick="add()">Click me</button>

<p id="amt1"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making the assignment in the local scope of the function, so every time the function executes, it's going to assign the value 1 to the 'sum' variable. Next, you're creating the variable 'adding' by trying to assign the value of adding, which doesn't exist yet.

It seems like the goal of your function is to just increment the value of 'amt1' by one.

```
function add(elId){
    let currentAmt = document.getElementById(elId).innerText; 
    currentAmt = parseInt(currentAmt) + 1; 
    document.getElementById(elId).innerText = currentAmt; 
}
```

By passing in the element ID, your function can now be applied to any element. It parses the integer from its current inner text, adds 1, then sets the new amount to the inner text of the element.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to have a look on this post- [Increment value each time when you run function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839918/increment-value-each-time-when-you-run-function)

about how to increment, the idea is keep the variable outside the function as in you case,

1. you dont need parseInt as its used for parsing integers from a string.
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt
2. you need to keep the sum variable outside function. following is the general function to add

```js
 var n = 0;
    function add(value){
       n += value;
       return n;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```js
 document.getElementById("amt1").addEventListener("click", displayDate);
function displayDate() {
var node = document.getElementById('amt1');
document.getElementById("amt1").innerHTML = parseInt(node.textContent)+1;
}
```

```html
<button id="amt1">1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an `undefined` variable `adding` to make your calculation that's why you get a `NaN` as a result :

- `var adding = adding + sum` : the variable `adding` isn't yet initialized so it's value equals to `undefined` which give us `var adding = undefined + sum = NaN`. See next example :

```js
var sum = parseInt(1);
console.log('typeof "adding" before initialization is ' + typeof adding + ' and it equals "' + adding + '"');
var adding = adding + sum;
console.log('typeof "adding" after initialization is ' + typeof adding + ' and it equals "' + adding + '"');
```

> BTW, you don't need `parseInt` in order to put manually a number, `sum = parseInt(1)` is the same as `sum = 1` but the later is faster.

And now here's how to accomplish your task :

```js
/**
 * btn: the button to be clicked to increment the counting.
 * counterTxt: the "p#counter" element that prints the counting.
 * counter: keeps track of the number of the clicks made.
**/
const btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
  counterTxt = document.getElementById('counter');
let counter = 0; /** holds the number of clicks **/

/** click event handler for the "button" **/
btn.addEventListener('click', () => counterTxt.textContent = ++counter); /** update the "p#counter" text and increment the counter **/
```

```html
<button id="btn">click to increment</button>
<p id="counter">0</p>
```