# Perform the operation, if the IF statement is true

Tags: javascript

I have recently started learning javascript and have already written some code. But at this I don't understand why it doesn't add 1 when the statement is true. It always prints 0.

```
var test = true
var value = 0

if(test === true){
    value + 1
}

console.log(value)
```

Comment: `value + 1;` doesn’t do anything. Did you mean `++value;` or `value += 1;` or `value = value + 1;`? Also, `if(test === true)` can be replaced by `if(test)`.

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment)

Comment: [Other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839918/increment-value-each-time-when-you-run-function/21839945)

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to write `value = value + 1` and just wrote `value + 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's how you add the one to the value.

```
var test = true
var value = 0

if(test === true){
    value++
}

console.log(value)
```